Best Practice Approach: Lambda Python SSM-Commands vs Python-LDAP library
What are the pros and cons of using an SSM agent to run AD Commands on a domain controller from the Python-Lambda function vs using the Python-LDAP library to fulfill the same operations?
We have an AD directory hosted in an EC2 instance and we are trying to build automation to create users, create groups, add/remove group members, and update user profiles.
I can run all PowerShell Commands from Lambda but Send-Commands executes commands without AD credentials.
command = f"Add-ADGroupMember -Identity '{group_name}' -Members '{user_principal}' -Confirm:$false -PassThru | ConvertTo-Json"

        response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id],
        DocumentName='AWS-RunPowerShellScript',
        Parameters={'commands': [command]},
        TimeoutSeconds=30,  # Adjust the timeout as necessary
    )
    print(f"Command response: {response}")
    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
    print(f"CommandId: {command_id}")
    # Wait a bit for command to execute; adjust the sleep time as necessary
    time.sleep(30)  # Wait for 10 seconds; adjust based on expected command execution time

    # Fetch command execution result
    output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=instance_id,
    )

